# Beautify URL in Angular JS Works Partially

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am fairly new to angular js. To beautify the URL's, I added

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in my config file and then

added `<base href='/myfolder/'`> in the  tag and changed the href links from `<a href="#!portfolio">` to `<a href="portfolio">`

When I run it in the server, what happens is when I click a link from the homepage the URL changes to the link i clicked but only the home page loads again. When I press F5(Refresh). The inner page loads and the URL changes correctly. Again when I press refresh it gives me a 404 error.

Ive explained the steps below.

Step 1

http://localhost/fps-ang/ (Homepage Loads)

Step2

Clicking portfolio link from the homepage is changing URL to this

http://localhost/fps-ang/#!portfolio but again only homepage loads.

Step 3:

Refresh the page and the url is changing to

http://localhost/fps-ang/portfolio The portfolio page loads (which is correct and initially should happen in step 2)

Step 4:

Hitting refresh again is giving 404 error.

Please help. I dont know what im doing wrong here.
I also tried changing htaccess to this

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

It did not work. Please help!

Comment: I think you're missing a slash here: http://localhost/fps-ang/#!portfolio should be http://localhost/fps-ang/#!/portfolio
Btw http://localhost/fps-ang/portfolio should work aswell

Comment: When I add a slash before the portfolio. It is not displaying anything.